# Set javascript variables from ajax request to mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax request to a mysql database and need to loop through the results and either set them as javascript variables or use them in functions within the loop.

mysql query where id is not unique and will return an array of results:

```
    $id =$_REQUEST['id'];
    $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM quote where id = :id");
    $sth->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    echo json_encode($result);
```

Ajax request using post and log results:

```
$.ajax({     
    type: "POST",
    data: "id="+id,
    url: "get-quote-data.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) { 
        console.log(result);
      }
   });
```

logs 2 objects in an array as there are currently 2 results:

```
    [{"id":"6776t2dhc3aq","0":"6776t2dhc3aq","Wid":"6776t2dhc3aqnew0.5981985541579144","1":"6776t2dhc3aqnew0.5981985541579144","room":"Plot 1 Bedroom","2":"Plot 1 Bedroom","style":"S150","3":"S150","type":"upvc","4":"upvc","colour":"0","5":"0","RAL":"","6":"","cill":"2","7":"2","width":"1023.0000","8":"1023.0000","height":"1585.0000","9":"1585.0000","fitting":"1","10":"1","comments":"","11":"","spacercol":"1","12":"1","glassstyle":"0","13":"0","handles":"0","14":"0","hinges":"0","15":"0","trickle":"0","16":"0","sash":"0","17":"0","fanlight":"0","18":"0","total":"0.0000","19":"0.0000","g1":"6","20":"6","g2":"6","21":"6","g3":"0","22":"0","g4":"0","23":"0","g5":"0","24":"0","g6":"0","25":"0","g7":"0","26":"0","g8":"0","27":"0","m1":"1023.0000","28":"1023.0000","m2":"1023.0000","29":"1023.0000","m3":"0.0000","30":"0.0000","m4":"0.0000","31":"0.0000","m5":"0.0000","32":"0.0000","m6":"0.0000","33":"0.0000","m7":"0.0000","34":"0.0000","m8":"0.0000","35":"0.0000","t1":"777.5000","36":"777.5000","t2":"777.5000","37":"777.5000","t3":"0.0000","38":"0.0000","t4":"0.0000","39":"0.0000","t5":"0.0000","40":"0.0000","t6":"0.0000","41":"0.0000","t7":"0.0000","42":"0.0000","t8":"0.0000","43":"0.0000","ICwinBor":"0","44":"0","LOF":"0","45":"0","LOH":"0","46":"0","intFinish":"0","47":"0","fEx":"0","48":"0","fExt":"0","49":"0","fExl":"0","50":"0","fExr":"0","51":"0","cler":"0","52":"0","fMul":"0","53":"0","commission":"666.999666","54":"666.999666","survey":"666.999666","55":"666.999666","NumItem":"1","56":"1","slideType":"","57":"","horns":"0","58":"0","vsLS":"0","59":"0","vsArched":"0","60":"0","vsFixed":"0","61":"0","vsSecure":"0","62":"0","vsPolished":"0","63":"0","vsJointed":"0","64":"0","vsBay":"0","65":"0","UPVCfStyle":"1","66":"1","UPVCbStyle":"1","67":"1","ALUfStyle":"1","68":"1","ALUbStyle":"1","69":"1","drain":"1","70":"1","ventPos":"1","71":"1","ALUProfile":"Alitherm 600","72":"Alitherm 600"},
{"id":"6776t2dhc3aq","0":"6776t2dhc3aq","Wid":"6776t2dhc3aqnew0.8957906831392683","1":"6776t2dhc3aqnew0.8957906831392683","room":"Plot 2 Bedroom","2":"Plot 2 Bedroom","style":"S150","3":"S150","type":"upvc","4":"upvc","colour":"0","5":"0","RAL":"","6":"","cill":"2","7":"2","width":"1023.0000","8":"1023.0000","height":"1585.0000","9":"1585.0000","fitting":"1","10":"1","comments":"","11":"","spacercol":"1","12":"1","glassstyle":"0","13":"0","handles":"0","14":"0","hinges":"0","15":"0","trickle":"0","16":"0","sash":"0","17":"0","fanlight":"0","18":"0","total":"0.0000","19":"0.0000","g1":"6","20":"6","g2":"6","21":"6","g3":"0","22":"0","g4":"0","23":"0","g5":"0","24":"0","g6":"0","25":"0","g7":"0","26":"0","g8":"0","27":"0","m1":"1023.0000","28":"1023.0000","m2":"1023.0000","29":"1023.0000","m3":"0.0000","30":"0.0000","m4":"0.0000","31":"0.0000","m5":"0.0000","32":"0.0000","m6":"0.0000","33":"0.0000","m7":"0.0000","34":"0.0000","m8":"0.0000","35":"0.0000","t1":"777.5000","36":"777.5000","t2":"777.5000","37":"777.5000","t3":"0.0000","38":"0.0000","t4":"0.0000","39":"0.0000","t5":"0.0000","40":"0.0000","t6":"0.0000","41":"0.0000","t7":"0.0000","42":"0.0000","t8":"0.0000","43":"0.0000","ICwinBor":"0","44":"0","LOF":"0","45":"0","LOH":"0","46":"0","intFinish":"0","47":"0","fEx":"0","48":"0","fExt":"0","49":"0","fExl":"0","50":"0","fExr":"0","51":"0","cler":"0","52":"0","fMul":"0","53":"0","commission":"666.999666","54":"666.999666","survey":"666.999666","55":"666.999666","NumItem":"1","56":"1","slideType":"","57":"","horns":"0","58":"0","vsLS":"0","59":"0","vsArched":"0","60":"0","vsFixed":"0","61":"0","vsSecure":"0","62":"0","vsPolished":"0","63":"0","vsJointed":"0","64":"0","vsBay":"0","65":"0","UPVCfStyle":"1","66":"1","UPVCbStyle":"1","67":"1","ALUfStyle":"1","68":"1","ALUbStyle":"1","69":"1","drain":"1","70":"1","ventPos":"1","71":"1","ALUProfile":"Alitherm 600","72":"Alitherm 600"}]
```

Within my success function I need to be able to loop through all of the results  in each object and use them as I require.

I have tried many of the answers posted on here with no luck, such as:

```
for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++){
        var windowid = result[j].Wid);
        console.log(windowid );
     }
```

logs undefined.
I have also tried many for in and foreach loop examples with no luck.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try printing `result.length`?

Comment: var windowid = result[j].Wid--------------->)<-----------------;

Comment: console.log(result.length); logs: 3827. Confused

Comment: removed the extra ) and still undefined

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ueg7dzke/ this works, so are you accessing `result`out of success function?

Comment: have your tried adding `dataType:'json'` to your request

Answer (score 0):

Parse the result as JSON before the for loop.
Add line `result = JSON.parse(result)` . As content-type header is not set to `application/json` your result will be a string which should be parsed as json.

Comment: i've tried both of these already and result is logged as: Array [ Object, Object ]

Answer (score 0):

First, you're returning in JSON format, so set that in the ajax request...

```
$.ajax({     
    type: "POST",
    data: "id="+id,
    url: "get-quote-data.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) { 
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Inside the success function, you can use $.each function to loop through your response...

```
$.each(result,function(id,value) {
    value['id']...
    value['Wid']...
    etc...
});
```

So, putting all together...

```
$.ajax({     
    type: "POST",
    data: "id="+id,
    url: "get-quote-data.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {

        $.each(result,function(id,value) {
            var windowid = value['Wid'];
            console.log(windowid);
        });
    }
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Great @MartynClinton! Happy to hear that!

Comment: Hey @MartynClinton, do you mind to vote or mark the answer as a solution? I'm new here and it will allow me to do more things. Thanks in advance!